# Order of a, order of ab, order of b in Zp

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, prime-numbers

Let the order of a be j, the order of b be k, and the order of ab be h in $Z_p$. Is $a^{hk} = 1 mod p$? Not sure if this is true or how I would show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
1=1^k=(ab)^{hk}=a^{hk}b^{hk}=a^{hk}
$$
in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $(ab)^{hk}\equiv ((ab)^h)^k \equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Similarly, $b^{hk}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

It follows that $(b^{-1})^{hk}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Finally,
$$a^{hk}\equiv (ab)^{hk}(b^{-1})^{hk}\equiv 1\pmod{p}.$$